# Insert into a table containing only identity column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following table :

```
CREATE TABLE Seq2 (val INT NOT NULL IDENTITY);
```

How to populate this table knowing that I tried this :

```
 INSERT INTO Seq2(val) VALUES (1)
```

I have the following error :

> Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'Seq2' when
> IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.

Comment: @Lamu gave the best answer (IMHO).  Now it's your turn.  WHY do you need to create such a table and what are you going to do with it?  I ask because, depending on what you're going to use the table for, there may be a much better answer.

Comment: @JeffModen I only gave one column of my table. I am working on a stored procedure to insert a record with SK=-1 in my dimension.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to satisfy my curiosity, @mohamed_mhin... I'm thinking that your post caused some distraction from your real problem.  Anyway, I'm glad it got resolved for you.

Answer (score 4):

Having such a table seems completely pointless, if I must say. If the table has only an `IDENTITY` then it effectively holds no meaning, so there's no point it being there.

That being said, if you did have such a table, you can `INSERT` values into the `IDENTITY` using `DEFAULT VALUES`:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.Seq2
DEFAULT VALUES;

INSERT INTO dbo.Seq2
DEFAULT VALUES;
```

With a new table, this would create rows with the values `1` and `2`.

If you want to explicitly `INSERT` values into the table, then you're better off remove the `IDENTITY` option. Considering this is a new table, just `DROP` it and recreate it with the `IDENTITY` property:

```
DROP TABLE dbo.Seq2;
GO
CREATE TABLE Seq2 (val INT NOT NULL);
```

Having a table with a single `IDENTITY` column, that you're then going to define the results for *really* is pointless. Either don't use `IDENTITY` and define the values, or use `IDENTITY` and let SQL Server handle it.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. (Though I disagree of the table being "completely pointless", but that's another story.)

Comment: It's more that I see a table with just an `IDENTITY` being pointless, @stickybit . a `SEQUENCE` would likely solve the problem the OP is trying to solve with a table with just an `IDENTITY`; and is far better at it (doesn't have issues like race conditions). A table with just an ID (not an `IDENTITY`), however, does have it uses. Perhaps I wasn't completely clear in my statement about it being "pointless".

Comment: Just an FYI to explain why someone may want to build such a table.  A "TALLY" table is frequently constructed using only an  IDENTITY column and is far from being useless.  I also voted up your post because of the DEFAULT VALUES method you used.

Comment: I couldn't gave the whole table definition due to privacy issues. I am aware that having a table with an identity column is pointless. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
 SET IDENTITY_INSERT Seq2 ON
 INSERT INTO Seq2(val)VALUES (1) 
SET IDENTITY_INSERT Seq2 OFF
```

Answer (score -1):

Simply, enable `IDENTITY_INSERT` for the table.  That looks like this:

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT IdentityTable ON

INSERT INTO Seq2(val) VALUES (1)

SET IDENTITY_INSERT IdentityTable OFF
```

Keep in mind :

- It can only be enabled on one table at a time.  If you try to enable
  it on a second table while it is still enabled on a first table SQL
  Server will generate an error.
- When it is enabled on a table you must specify a value for the
  identity column.
- The user issuing the statement must own the object, be a system
  administrator (sysadmin role), be the database owner (dbo) or be a
  member of the db_ddladmin role in order to run the command.

  `SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()` // to get last identity value generated in the same session and scope

  `SELECT @@IDENTITY` // to get the last identity vaue generated in a session irrespective of scope

Comment: This makes the `IDENTITY` property completely pointless though, the OP would be better off just remove the `IDENTITY` property if that is the case.